# What type do I use for a Sequence of Strings

Tags: swift

I want to write a function that accepts an argument that is a Sequence of Strings (not necessarily an array of Strings, but anything that implements the Sequence protocol where the items in the sequence are Strings).

Actually, I'd like to pass in the keys to a dictionary that is keyed by strings (preferably, without creating a temporary array).

I can't seem to find the right syntax to specify that type for the argument.

Comment: Note that accepting a generic `Sequence` will be much broader than Collection but also too restrictive. Many properties and methods `(i.e: count, append, …)` won't be available. Make sure you won't need to access those properties when deciding which protocol to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func doSomething<S: Sequence>(with seq: S) where S.Element == String
```

Or as per suggestion in comments by @LeoDabus you could include also substrings and other types conforming to StringProtocol by constraining the sequence’s element:

```
func doSomething<S: Sequence>(with seq: S) where S.Element: StringProtocol
```

Comment: You don't need `.Iterator` here. `S.Element` is sufficient (and the more common way to write this).

Comment: @Rob I know, I still prefer the old signature I am going to change the answer though.

Comment: @valeCocoa you should use `S.Element: StringProtocol` to support substrings as well

Comment: Btw your syntax is wrong. You should be using `==` not `=`.

Comment: @LeoDabus sure, that’s true. Indeed at first I thought using that signature too,  but then I decided to stick to the question.

Comment: @LeoDabus dang! Thanks. We shall have auto-completion in SO editor! 